# Finding matrix of a linear operator respecting a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $\phi$ belongs to $\text{Hom}\left(\mathbb{R}^{3}\right)$ and has in respect to $E$ (the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$) has a matrix $$f=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        3 & 5 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix},$$
Find the matrix $J$ of $\phi$ respecting the basis $A$, where $$A=\left\{a_1=(9,0,9),a_2=(0,3,5),a_3=(3,-3,-1)\right\}.$$

Comment: I would like some instructions...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider the matrix that has as columns the vectors of the basis $A$
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
9&0&3\\
0&3&-3\\
9&5&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If $\vec x$ is a vector that has components in the standard basis $[x_i]_S^T$ than its components in the basis $A$ are $[x_i]_A^T=A^{-1}[x_i]_S^T$ so that we have $[x_i]_S^T=A[x_i]_A^T$.

In the standard basis the linear transformation $\phi$ is represented by the matrix $F$ ( your $f$) that acts as:
$$
[\phi(\vec x)_i]_S^T=F[x_i]_S^T=FA[x_i]_A^T
$$
and if you want $\phi(\vec x)$ in the base $A$ you have to transform as:
$$
[\phi(\vec x)_i]_A^T=A^{-1}[\phi(\vec x)_i]_S^T
$$

Comment: i'm confused... can I see the calculations?

Comment: You have:  $J=A^{-1}FA$